# Handling onChange event for MaterialUI drop down element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to validate the MaterialUI TextField (Country list) component wrapped with Autocomplete using onChange event and use it to enable the Submit button if the field (the country) is filled in. But I'm facing an issue once I'm not entering the country name by hands but selecting it from the dropdown. It looks like onChange event does not see the change in case of selecting from the drop down. (Sorry for formatting issues)

```js
// countries: [a,b,c,d];

<Autocomplete
    options={countries as CountryType[]}

<TextField 
    onChange={(event)=>{setFormValue({
        ...formValue, 
        country: event.target.value
    })}}
/>
```

After this I'm using it on enabling the button:

```ts
<Button 
    disableElevation 
    disabled={formValue.country===""}
> 
    Submit
</Button>
```

Would be very appreciated on some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `TextField`'s `onChange` method is obviously handling changes of the `TextField`. It doesn't fire on value selection. You're better off removing `TextField`'s `onChange` handler and assign [`onInputChange`](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) property of the `Autocomplete` component that does exactly what you're looking for:

```ts
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={countries}
    ...
    onInputChange={(_, value) => {
        setFormValue({
            ...formValue, 
            country: value
        })
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField ...  /> {/* without onChange handler */}
    )}
/>
```

Comment: This solution worked exactly how it was required. Thanks a lot for the solution!